# Cassandra Spark sqlContext, Input path does not exist: cfs://127.0.0.1/home/1.csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to import a CSV file with Spark :

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext
                        .read()
                        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .load("/home/1.csv");
```

But I have this error message:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist: cfs://home/1.csv

So I can see two ways of solving this issue:

1- how can i put my file into cfs://127.0.0.1/home/1.csv

or

2 how can i tell load() to actually look at /home/1.csv

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you try using `file:///home/1.csv`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works fine !